# How can I swap half of two columns in a pandas dataframe in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to create a machine learning model and teaching myself as I go.  I will be working with a large dataset, but before I get to that, I am practicing with a smaller dataset to make sure everything is working as expected. I will need to swap half of the rows of two columns in my dataset, and I am not sure how to accomplish this.

Say I have a dataframe like the below:

| index | number | letter |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | A |
| 1 | 2 | B |
| 2 | 3 | C |
| 3 | 4 | D |
| 4 | 5 | E |
| 5 | 6 | F |

I want to randomly swap half of the rows of the number and letter columns, so one output could look like this:

| index | number | letter |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | A |
| 1 | B | 2 |
| 2 | 3 | C |
| 3 | D | 4 |
| 4 | 5 | E |
| 5 | F | 6 |

Is there a way to do this in python?

edit: thank you for all of your answers, I greatly appreciate it! :)

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

To select randomly rows, use `np.random.choice`:

```
import numpy as np

idx = np.random.choice(df.index, len(df) // 2, replace=False)
df.loc[idx, ['letter', 'number']] = df.loc[idx, ['number', 'letter']].to_numpy()
print(df)

# Output
  number letter
0      1      A
1      2      B
2      3      C
3      D      4
4      E      5
5      F      6
```

---

**Old answer**

You can try:

```
df.loc[df.index % 2 == 1, ['letter', 'number']] = \
    df.loc[df.index % 2 == 1, ['number', 'letter']].to_numpy()
print(df)

# Output
  number letter
0      1      A
1      B      2
2      3      C
3      D      4
4      5      E
5      F      6
```

For more readability, use an intermediate variable as a boolean mask:

```
mask = df.index % 2 == 1
df.loc[mask, ['letter', 'number']] = df.loc[mask, ['number', 'letter']].to_numpy()
```

Comment: I'd have done the same

Comment: OP states that they want to **randomly** swap half the rows

Comment: @BenGrossmann. Thanks to point me out. I updated my answer. Nice solution.

Comment: @Corralien No problem, and thanks. By the way, is there any particular reason that you used `.to_numpy()` rather than `.values` like I did? I've seen both and I'm never sure if/when one is better than the other.

Comment: Yes I really have a good reason :-) https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.values.html. However I prefer `values` but I think there is a reason of logic: `to_list`, `to_dict`, `to_excel`, ... so `to_numpy`

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to implement this.

```
import pandas as pd
from random import sample

df = pd.DataFrame({'index':range(6),'number':range(1,7),'letter':[*'ABCDEF']}).set_index('index')

n = len(df)
idx = sample(range(n),k=n//2)                  # randomly select which rows to switch
df = df.iloc[idx,:] = df.iloc[idx,::-1].values # switch those rows
```

An example result is

```
      number letter
index              
0          1      A
1          2      B
2          C      3
3          4      D
4          E      5
5          F      6
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a copy of your original data, sample it, and then update it inplace- converting to a numpy ndarray to prevent index-alignment from occuring.

```py
swapped_df = df.copy()
sample = swapped_df.sample(frac=0.5, random_state=0)
swapped_df.loc[sample.index, ['number', 'letter']] = sample[['letter', 'number']].to_numpy()

print(swapped_df)
      number letter
index              
0          1      A
1          B      2
2          C      3
3          4      D
4          E      5
5          6      F
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to previous answers but slightly more readable (in my opinion) if you are trying to build your sense for basic pandas operations:

```
rows_to_change = df.sample(frac=0.5)
rows_to_change = rows_to_change.rename(columns={'number':'letter', 'letter':'number'})
df.loc[rows_to_change.index] = rows_to_change
```